# Subtract percentage from percentage and avoid 0 value and decimals Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

[image]
I need to find a formula to make value of **M13** = `(100% - (K13+K14))`
The expected output to be `82` ,but because I rounded up **K13** to avoid 0 percentage, then now value of M13= 83% 
and that is wrong, as sum of (M13+K13+K14) should be 100% 
greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: The formula `=J14/J15` is not the same as `1%`. Like you said, it's **visually** rounded to show the user a value of `1%`. The actual numeric value is lower. The same with your `17%`. So the value of `83%` is more "correct" than if it would be `82%`. Maybe the solution to you and your users is to avoid showing whole numbers and instead allow for some decimals. The more decimals, the more accurate.

Comment: @JvdV ,you are correct about `visually rounded`, unfortunately decimals is not option , that's why `(M13+K13+K14) should be 100%`

Comment: Visually representation of values is not something Excel calculates with. One thing you could do is `=100%-(SUM(J1:J2)/J3)`, bypassing the values in column K. However, it's not guaranteed it's going to be the expected output in all cases.

Comment: Then use round(), roundup() and rounddown(0 to control as needed.

Comment: I would  like to recommend the next solution: Change the format of `Decimal Places` (in Percentage category) to be **2**. In this way, it will not display 0, it will display `0.84%` and `16.74%`. In "M13` it will display `82,43`... If you want making the last one to round (at 82, now) you may format there percentage with 0 decimals and it will show `82`.

Comment: @JvdV ,your last suggestions works correctly, you can post as answer

Comment: HI @Waleed, my answer considered you only want to round up K14 (as your image indicates) and you want the user to visually see the sum of percentages equals to 100%. If you need something different, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can roundup your number as a formula. This way, it will work for any two input numbers.

On this solution, the formula on K14 becomes `=ROUNDUP(J14/J15,2)`
The "2" means two decimals -- which is zero decimals in percentage notation.

Then you can use your formula on M13 normally: `=100%-(SUM(K13:K14))`

Comment: Using `=ROUNDUP(J14/J15,2)` on K14 is correct, but after I used on M13 `=100%-(SUM(K13:K14))` the result is .82 and even rounded up will become **1**

Comment: But why do you want to round up M13? If it is .82, it is right (82%). You just need to change the format to percentage.